# How to create Self-Sign certificate through InstallScript functions?

Tags: openssl, installshield, installscript-msi, self-signed-certificate

I have InstallScript MSI installer project in InstallShield. I wanted to create Self-Sign certificate during the installation of my product. So is there any windows APIs I can use in InstallScript code OR are there any InstallScript functions using which I can create Self-Sign certificate during installation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can handle it from InstallShield. Can you please give us more details about your scenario?

To generate a self-signed certificate you can use a powershell cmdlet. The [New-SelfSignedCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps) cmdlet allows to create a self-signed certificate for testing purpose (may required administrator rights).

You can also take a look on the [Generate a self-signed certificate for code signing](https://www.meziantou.net/2017/03/25/generate-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing) article which may be useful to you.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to create a self-sign certificate.

Answer (score 0):

While I think it's likely that you can do this with [UseDLL](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/Subsystems/LangRef/LangRef.htm#helplibrary/LangrefUseDLL.htm) and friends in InstallScript, by the time you're done prototype-ing the relevant structures and functions, you'll probably be happier with a pure C++ implementation.

For either the InstallScript or C++ route, you'll have to understand the C++ layer. The core of it is [CertCreateSelfSignCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certcreateselfsigncertificate) from [wincrypt.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/). You'll note very quickly that CertCreateSelfSignCertificate requires several parameters, some of which need to have been initialized by calling other functions. So, for a little while, understanding or implementing this is going to feel like diving down a rabbit hole.

But there's an example in the SDK: [cryptoapi/CreateCertificate](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/security/cryptoapi/CreateCertificate). It's only 549 lines, and a significant chunk of that is for handling command lines. And you can find several other examples by searching for 'CreateSelfSignCertificate example'. But regardless, it's still not a trivial task to do correctly.

So you may well be happiest with an alternate approach like J. Tribbiani's suggestion of using PowerShell.